# "While paying" vs "while paid"

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs

What would be the right option: paid or paying? I think paying.

> He took ten years to earn his bachelor's degree while **paid/paying** his bills by working part time as a ski instructor.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, "paying" is the right choice here. If you wanted to use "paid" you would need to add a "he" in front like this:

> He took ten years to earn his bachelor's degree while **he paid** his bills...

Personally, I think "while paying" flows easier off the tongue. It also has the advantage of matching the tense of "working" later in the sentence.

Comment: Thank you **Mr. @Josh** for the explanation. Appreciate :)

Comment: You're welcome, what's up?

Comment: Take a look at the following sentence:
===
His mission to become an actor looked impossible when he auditioned for a role in the television version of Fame, **as** the casting director told Cruise that he wasn't pretty enough.
===
Does "as" sound better, or I should start a new sentence or anything else?

Comment: His mission to become an actor **seemed** impossible when he auditioned for a role in the television version of Fame, as the casting director told Cruise that he wasn't **handsome** enough.

Comment: Unless the direct quote says "pretty", I would change this to "handsome" since pretty is typically used to describe a woman's beauty not a man's. But yes, to answer your question "as" is ok to use here.

Comment: Oh, seemed sounds nice here. You're right on pretty too. If I use em-dash: ... television version of Fame—the casting director told Cruise that he wasn't handsome enough.

Comment: It may be tempting to use an em dash, but no I would not use it in this case. It sounds better with "as" or even try "... television version of Fame, **because** the casting director told Cruise that he wasn't handsome enough."

Comment: I think the word 'pretty' when applied to an actor of known good looks, works perfectly. It's very 'theatrical'.  … but this should all be a separate question, btw.

Comment: I disagree, it implies femininity. Unless that's what he's going for. But another alternative to pretty and handsome would be "he wasn't **good-looking** enough."

Comment: I got a solution. I put them in quote: "pretty enough". :)

Comment: As long as you're happy!